# MSXMLDomDocument to consume XML

Tags: c++, com, domdocument, msxml

I have an existing MSXML2::DOMDocument. Into that Document I want to insert further XML from text.

What I have tried is creating a second DOMDocument and using its loadXML method. Then I append its documentElemt to my main XmlDocument.
This gives me a memory leak. I guess shifting Nodes from one Doc to another is not valid.

So my question is: what is the intended way to insert XMLSource (text) into an existing DomDocument?

Comment: You may be looking for [`IXMLDOMDocument3::importNode`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms767525.aspx)